# Precise definition of "functional interface" in Java 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, abstract, functional-interface

Recently I started exploring Java 8 and I can't quite understand the concept of "functional interface" that is essential to Java's implementation of lambda expressions. There is a [pretty comprehensive guide](http://www.lambdafaq.org/) to lambda functions in Java, but I got stuck on [the chapter that gives definition to the concept of functional interfaces](http://www.lambdafaq.org/what-is-a-functional-interface/). The definition reads:

> More precisely, a functional interface is defined as any interface that has exactly one abstract method.

An then he proceeds to examples, one of which is `Comparator` interface:

> ```
> public interface Comparator<T> {
>     int compare(T o1, T o2);
>     boolean equals(Object obj);
> }
> ```

I was able to test that I can use a lambda function in place of Comparator argument and it works(i.e. `Collections.sort(list, (a, b) -> a-b)`).

But in the Comparator interface both `compare` and `equals` methods are abstract, which means it has **two abstract methods**. So how can this be working, if the definition requires an interface to have **exactly one abstract method**? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

From the [same page you linked to](http://www.lambdafaq.org/what-is-a-functional-interface/):

> The interface Comparator is functional because although it declares two abstract methods, one of these—equals— has a signature corresponding to a public method in Object. Interfaces always declare abstract methods corresponding to the public methods of Object, but they usually do so implicitly. Whether implicitly or explicitly declared, such methods are excluded from the count.

I can't really say it better.

Comment: But then, since we can't have a primitive that `extends` anything since they are not objects, and since any class created in Java `extends Object`, what is the purpose of having `boolean equals(Object obj);` in there? Any implementation will have access to that method anyways. Is it purely to emphasise the fact that this method is a great candidate to being modified for some `Comparable` implementations?

Answer (score 16):

Another explanation is given in the [@FunctionalInterface page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html):

> Conceptually, a functional interface has exactly one abstract method. Since default methods have an implementation, they are not abstract. **If an interface declares an abstract method overriding one of the public methods of `java.lang.Object`, that also does not count toward the interface's abstract method count since any implementation of the interface will have an implementation from `java.lang.Object` or elsewhere.**

You can test which interface is a correct **functional interface** using  **`@FunctionalInterface`**.

E.g.:

- this works

  ```
  @FunctionalInterface
  public interface FunctionalInterf {

      void m();

      boolean equals(Object o);

  }
  ```
- this generates an error:

  ```
  @FunctionalInterface
  public interface FunctionalInterf {

      void m();

      boolean equals();

  }
  ```

  > Multiple non-overriding abstract methods found in interface FunctionalInterf

Comment: but then the interface should extends Object, to have this Override scenario as valid.

Answer (score 4):

Q. But in the Comparator interface both compare() and equals() methods are abstract, which means it has two abstract methods. So how can this be working, if the definition requires an interface to have exactly one abstract method? What am I missing here?

A.

> A functional interface may specify any public method defined by Object, such as equals( ),
>   without affecting its “functional interface” status. The public Object methods are considered implicit
>   members of a functional interface because they are automatically implemented by an instance of a
>   functional interface.

Comment: Do you have a link to the source of the quote? Thanks!

Comment: You can see Introducing Lambda section in http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/newtojava/java8book-2172125.pdf.

Answer (score 2):

An interface cannot extend Object class, because Interface has to have public and abstract methods.

For every public method in the Object class, there is an implicit public and abstract method in an interface.

This is the standard Java Language Specification which states like this,

> “If an interface has no direct super interfaces, then the interface implicitly declares a public abstract member method m with signature s, return type r, and throws clause t corresponding to each public instance method m with signature s, return type r, and throws clause t declared in Object, unless a method with the same signature, same return type, and a compatible throws clause is explicitly declared by the interface.”

That's how Object class' methods are declared in an interface. And according to JLS, this does not count as interface' abstract method. Hence, Comparator interface is a functional interface.

Answer (score 1):

**A functional interface has only one abstract method but it can have multiple default and static methods.**

Since default methods are not abstract you’re free to add default methods to your functional interface as many as you like.

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface MyFuctionalInterface 
{
public void perform();

default void perform1(){
//Method body
}

default void perform2(){
//Method body
}
}
```

If an interface declares an abstract method overriding one of the public methods of `java.lang.Object`, that also does not count toward the interface’s abstract method count since any implementation of the interface will have an implementation from `java.lang.Object` or elsewhere.

**Comparator** is a functional interface even though it declared two abstract methods. Because one of these abstract methods “`equals()`” which has signature equal to public method in Object class.
e.g. Below interface is a valid functional interface.

```
@FunctionalInterface
    public interface MyFuctionalInterface 
    {
    public void perform();
 
    @Override
    public String toString();                //Overridden from Object class
 
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj);        //Overridden from Object class
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a "show me the code" approach to understanding the definition:
we shall look into OpenJDK `javac` for how it checks validity of classes annotated with `@FunctionalInterface`.

The most recent (as of July, 2022) implementation lies here:
[com/sun/tools/javac/code/Types.java#L735-L791](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/226b8e680a82096b3d268703872d30182c10e326/src/jdk.compiler/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/code/Types.java#L735-L791):

```java
/**
 * Compute the function descriptor associated with a given functional interface
 */
public FunctionDescriptor findDescriptorInternal(TypeSymbol origin,
        CompoundScope membersCache) throws FunctionDescriptorLookupError {
    // ...
}
```

### Class Restriction

```java
if (!origin.isInterface() || (origin.flags() & ANNOTATION) != 0 || origin.isSealed()) {
    //t must be an interface
    throw failure("not.a.functional.intf", origin);
}
```

Pretty simple: the class must be an interface and must not be a sealed one.

### Member Restriction

```java
for (Symbol sym : membersCache.getSymbols(new DescriptorFilter(origin))) { /* ... */ }
```

In this loop, `javac` goes through the members of the `origin` class, using a `DescriptorFilter` to retrieve:

- Method members (of course)
- `&&` that are `abstract` but not `default`,
- `&&` and do not overwrite methods from `Object`,
- `&&` with their top level declaration not a `default` one.

If there is only one method matching all the above conditions, then surely it is a valid functional interface, and any lambda will overwrite that very method.

However, if there are multiple, `javac` tries to merge them:

- If those methods all share the same name, related by [*override equivalence*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2):

  - then we filter them into a `abstracts` collection:

    ```
    if (!abstracts.stream().filter(msym -> msym.owner.isSubClass(sym.enclClass(), Types.this))
            .map(msym -> memberType(origin.type, msym))
            .anyMatch(abstractMType -> isSubSignature(abstractMType, mtype))) {
        abstracts.append(sym);
    }
    ```

    Methods are filtered out if:

    - their enclosing class is super class of that of another previously matched method,
    - and the signature of that previously matched method is [*subsignature*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2) of that of this method.
- Otherwise, the functional interface is not valid.

Having collected `abstracts`, `javac` then goes to `mergeDescriptors`, which uses `mergeAbstracts`, which I will just quote from its comments:

```java
/**
 * Merge multiple abstract methods. The preferred method is a method that is a subsignature
 * of all the other signatures and whose return type is more specific {@see MostSpecificReturnCheck}.
 * The resulting preferred method has a thrown clause that is the intersection of the merged
 * methods' clauses.
 */
public Optional<Symbol> mergeAbstracts(List<Symbol> ambiguousInOrder, Type site, boolean sigCheck) {
    // ...
}
```

### Conclusion

1. Functional interfaces must be interfaces :P , and must not be `sealed` or annotations.
2. Methods are searched in the whole inheritance tree.
3. Methods overlapping with those from `Object` are ignored.
4. `default` methods are ignored, unless they are later overridden by sub-interfaces as non-default.
5. Matching methods must all share the same name, related by override equivalence.
6. Either there is only one method matching the above conditions, or matching methods can get "merged" by their class hierarchy, subsignature relations, return types and thrown clauses.

Answer (score -1):

The Java docs say:

> Note that it is always safe not to override Object.equals(Object).
>   However, overriding this method may, in some cases, improve
>   performance by allowing programs to determine that two distinct
>   comparators impose the same order.

Maybe Comparator is special? Maybe, even though it's an interface, there is somehow a default implementation of `equals()` that calls `compare()`? Algorithmically, it's trivial.

I thought all methods that were declared in interfaces were abstract (i. e. no default implementation). But maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: `Comparator` isn't special. When you create a new `Comparator` object it inherits from `Object`, including the concrete `equals` method.  Your comment that all methods declared in interfaces are abstract is no longer true in general, but it is true of the `equals` method in `Comparator`. My comment to Mark Peters' answer explains this more, or see the syntax comment on the Lambda FAQ page http://www.lambdafaq.org/what-is-a-functional-interface/

Answer (score -1):

**Definition:**

If an interface contains only one abstract method, then such type of interface is called functional interface.

**Usage:**

1. Once we write Lambda expression "->" to invoke its functionality ,
   then in this context we require Functional Interface.
2. We can use the Functional Interface reference to refer Lambda
   expression.
3. Inside functional interface we can have one abstract method and n
   number of default/static methods.

**Functional interface with respect to inheritance:**

If an interface extends Functional interface and the child interface does not contain any abstract method , then the child interface is also considered to be Functional Interface.

**Functional interface is not new to java, its already used in following interface API's:**

1. Runnable : contains run() method only.
2. Callable : contains call() method only.
3. Comparable : contains compareTo() method only.

Answer (score -1):

Before Java 8, an interface could only declare one or more methods also known as Abstract Method (method with no implementation, just the signature). Starting with Java 8 an interface can also have implementation of one or more methods (knows as Interface Default Method) and static methods along with abstract methods. Interface Default Methods are marked default keyword.

So the question is, what is Functional Interface?
An interface with Single Abstract Method (SAM) is called Functional Interface.

Which means -

1. An interface with Single Abstract Method is a Functional Interface
2. An interface with Single Abstract Method and zero or more default
   methods and zero or more static method is also a valid Functional
   Interface.

More detail with example code https://readtorakesh.com/functional-interface-java8/