# Functional Term for a Single Method Interface

Tags: java, design-patterns

I lost recently the name of a kind of Java interface (language actually does not matter) like Comparable, Runnable,... which share the same principle: they only contain one single method to be implemented.

You have dozen of these interfaces in Java as well, like ActionListener, Cloneable,...

Note that I am not looking for the possible usages of such interfaces, just the title Java reference guides and books have given to such kind of interface.

By the way, the answer I'm searching for is not *closure*.

Comment: In Java (8), it is called [a functional interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14655913/precise-definition-of-functional-interface-in-java-8)

Comment: Role Interface? http://martinfowler.com/bliki/RoleInterface.html

Comment: It's also called a SAM (Single Abstract Method).

Comment: Great! Thanks for your answers, this was exactly the name(s) I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

As listed in the 3 question's comment, names of such interface are:

- Functional Interface
- Role Interface
- or SAM (Single Abstract Method)