# Can any interface with a single method, be considered a Functional Interface?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, functional-interface

For instance I have this Interface:

```
package tester;

public interface Calculator{

     public int calculate(int a,int b);

}
```

or

```
package tester;

@FunctionalInterface
public interface Calculator{

    public int calculate(int a,int b);

}
```

I can treat the first one as a functional interface too. For example :

```
package tester;
public class A {

    int a;
    int b;
    int sum;
    A(Calculator c,int e, int d){
        a=e;
        b=d;
        sum =c.calculate(a, b);

    }
    int get(){
        return sum;
    }
}
```

The class runner

```
package tester;

public class runner {

    public static void main(String a[]){

        System.out.println(new A((x,b)-> (x+b),1,2).get());
    }
}
```

The code works with or without the annotations, then why annotations?
Why can't it be said that any interface with a single method can be a functional interface?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14655913/2711488

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes any interface with one abstract method to implement can be a functional interface, the annotation `FunctionalInterface` is not required, it is only an **informative** annotation as stated into the javadoc.

> An **informative** annotation type used to indicate that an interface
>   type declaration is intended to be a *functional interface* as defined
>   by the Java Language Specification.
>
> ...
>
> However, the compiler will treat **any interface** meeting the definition
>   of a functional interface as a functional interface **regardless of
>   whether or not a `FunctionalInterface` annotation is present** on the
>   interface declaration.

Answer (score 7):

FuntionalInterface annotation is only a hint for a compiler and yes, any interface with one abstract method can be a functional interface. Annotation could be helpful to detect a mistake in functional interface. For example:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ExampleInterface {
}
```

would cause compilation error.