# How to implement RowMapper using java lambda expression

Tags: java, spring, lambda, jdbctemplate

I had a working RowMapper code that maps database table row in to a java object. I wanted to change the implementation using lambda expression. However, I am always getting error; Code snippet as follows;

```
String queryString = "select * from person where person_id = ? ";
RowMapper rowMapper = (rs, rowNum) -> {

Person p = new Person();

p.setName(rs.getString("personName"));
p.setAddress(rs.getString("address"));
p.setAge(rs.getInt("age"));
}

Person person = getJdbcTemplate().query(queryString, personId, rowMapper);

return person;
```

Can someone help me to implement code correctly?
Any idea to get list of persons?

Comment: What is the compilation error. Did you miss a semicolon after `}`?. Is `RowMapper` a functional interface? What version of spring are you using?

Comment: Yes, once I add semicolon compiler asked to add return statement inside the lambda. However, I need to return person object.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[`RowMapper`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowMapper.html) is a interface with a single abstract method (not inheriting from a method of `Object`), so [it can be considered a functional interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14655913/precise-definition-of-functional-interface-in-java-8). Its functional method takes a `ResultSet` and a `int`, and returns an object.

The first problem with the code is that the type of the object returned is a generic type of the interface. As currently used with `RowMapper`, you're using a raw-type, [which you shouldn't do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it). The second issue is that the lambda expression does not return any object, so it cannot conform to the functional method which except an object to be returned.

As such, a corrected code would be:

```
RowMapper<Person> rowMapper = (rs, rowNum) -> {
    Person p = new Person();
    p.setName(rs.getString("personName"));
    p.setAddress(rs.getString("address"));
    p.setAge(rs.getInt("age"));
    return p;
};
```

Comment: I got error when I compile the code.

311: error: ')' expected
RowMapper<Person> rowMapper = (rs, rowNum) -> {

@Tunaki any idea with this...??

Comment: Probably due to code around that @Gayath. Look at lines before. If you take the snippet in this answer alone, it compiles fine.

Answer (score 5):

RowMapper using lambda expression example:

```
return jdbcTemplate.query(" select Scale_Point,Scale_Head from TEval_Scale ", new Object[] {},
                (resultSet, rowNum) ->{

                    TEvalScale tEvalScale = new TEvalScale();
                    tEvalScale.setScalePoint(resultSet.getInt("Scale_Point"));
                    tEvalScale.setScaleHead(resultSet.getString("Scale_Head"));
                    return tEvalScale;

                });
```

Answer (score 4):

@Tunaki is correct. Here is the shorthand version:

```
RowMapper<Person> rowMapper = (rs, rowNum) -> new Person(rs.getString("personName"), rs.getString("address"),rs.getInt("age")) ;
```

The brackets and the return aren't needed as they are implied.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to @Tunaki answer.

```
RowMapper<Person> rowMapper = (rs, rowNum) -> {
    Person p = new Person();
    p.setName(rs.getString("personName"));
    p.setAddress(rs.getString("address"));
    p.setAge(rs.getInt("age"));
    return p;
};

Map<String, Object> paramMap = new HashMap<>();
paramMap.put("person_id", personId);
```

If you want to get single Person :

```
Person person = getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(queryString, paramMap, rowMapper);
```

If you want to get List of Person :

```
List<Person> personList = getJdbcTemplate().query(queryString, paramMap, rowMapper);
```